# Linked list with nodes

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to make a linked list and test it in c++ using nodes. I create six nodes and then I print them forward and backwards like this:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

void TestAddHead();

int main()
{
    TestAddHead();

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}

void TestAddHead()
{
    cout << "Testing AddHead()" << endl;
    LinkedList<int> data;
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i += 2)
        data.AddHead(i);
    cout << "Node count: " << data.NodeCount() << endl;
    cout << "Print list forward:" << endl;
    data.PrintForward();
    cout << "Print list in reverse:" << endl;
    data.PrintReverse();
}
```

**LinkedList.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class LinkedList
{
public:
    struct Node
    {
        T data_;
        Node* next;
        Node* previous;
    };

    void PrintForward() const;
    void PrintReverse() const;
    unsigned int NodeCount() const;
    void AddHead(const T &data);
    LinkedList();
    LinkedList(const LinkedList<T> &list);
    ~LinkedList();

private:
    Node* head = new Node;
    Node* tail = new Node;
    unsigned int count = 0;
};

template<typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList()
{

}

template<typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(const LinkedList<T> &list)
{

}

template<typename T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList()
{

}

template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::AddHead(const T &data)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node;

    newNode->data_ = data;

    if (count == 0)
    {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
        head->next = nullptr;
        head->previous = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        newNode->next = head;
        head->previous = newNode;
        head = newNode;
    }
    count = count + 1;
}

template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::PrintForward() const
{
    Node* currentNode = head;
    while (currentNode != nullptr)
    {
        cout << currentNode->data_ << endl;
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::PrintReverse() const
{
    Node* currentNode2 = tail;
    while (currentNode2 != nullptr)
    {
        cout << currentNode2->data_ << endl;
        currentNode2 = currentNode2->previous;
    }
}

template<typename T>
unsigned int LinkedList<T>::NodeCount() const
{
    return count;
}
```

this should be the output of the program:

Testing AddHead()
Node count: 6
Print list forward:
10
8
6
4
2
0
Print list in reverse:
0
2
4
6
8
10

The program works and gives me the correct output but the problem is that it just crashes when it reaches the "10" at the bottom of the program and I don't know why, can anyone tell me why is this happening and a possible way to fix it? thank you

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. This is probably just one file without any template code. This is actually required by the site rules, because in many cases this already allows you to find the error yourself. However, think about what happens at the end of your program: Destructors. Make sure those work. Also, there's a skill you could use, which is stepping through code with a debugger. Do some research on that and learn it, it is a required skill for any programmer.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Why are you looping in reverse until you see a null pointer?  Is the first node in the list `nullptr`?  Before writing code when implementing a linked list, it is always best to draw the list on paper using boxes as the data, and lines as the links.   Again, does that "reverse" loop make sense to you (i.e. when to stop looping) if you were to draw what you are doing on paper?

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate problem, you never set the new node `previous` pointer to `nullptr` ( a problem that honestly should be rectified by a better constructed loop and/or a proper constructor for `Node`). Regardless, here...

```
template<typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::AddHead(const T &data)
{
    Node* newNode = new Node;

    newNode->data_ = data;

    if (count == 0)
    {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
        head->next = nullptr;
        head->previous = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        newNode->next = head;
        newNode->previous = nullptr; // ADD THIS
        head->previous = newNode;
        head = newNode;

    }
    count = count + 1;
}
```

There are still several things wrong in this: memory leaks, empty copy-ctor and destructor, etc, but the above is the root of the current evil. That line could also be:

```
newNode->previous = head->previous;
```

but frankly that just confuses what you're doing. You're always landing your new nodes at the head of the list, so the `previous` member of said-same will always be `nullptr` (at least until you start studying circular lists).